# Redirect packets to server on other interface

Tags: iptables

Alright, little complex but here's what I need:

I have a Minecraft server in a ZeroTier network with an IP of 172.24.229.62, accepting connections on port 25565. The fact that it's ZeroTier doesn't particularly matter, just pretend it's a normal LAN.

On that same network, I have a general purpose Azure server with an IP of 172.24.229.65 on the LAN (ZeroTier) side. This LAN has no connection to the internet and no other devices. The general purpose server is running Ubuntu Server 20.10, and is exposed to the internet on another interface, accepting connections on port 25565.

I need this general purpose server to redirect incoming packets on port 25565 on the internet side to port 25565 of the Minecraft server on the LAN side and send packets back as well.

I found this script on SE, and tried it, but it didn't work. What am I doing wrong?

```
#!/bin/sh

echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward

iptables -F
iptables -t nat -F
iptables -X

iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 25565 -j DNAT --to-destination 172.24.229.62:25565
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -p tcp -d 172.24.229.62 --dport 25565 -j SNAT --to-source 172.24.229.65
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are almost there my friend. The only missing part is to configure a default gateway on Minecraft server. Ubuntu general server will act as the gateway in this case. From Minecraft server, execute the following command:

```
$ sudo ip route add default via 172.24.229.65
```